# Gradle Sync on Android Studio 1.2.1.1 running on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, ubuntu-14.04

I'm new on Android Studio and I'm trying to make it work on my Ubuntu 14.04, but every time that I try to start working on a new app, a Gradle sync error shows up:

Gradle project sync failed. 
Error:Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

I've been googling it for two days but didn't find any useful solution yet, do you guys have any idea of what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution`?